# Intercepts the registration of every inline events on the static node of the document

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

Using JavaScript, I want to intercept the registration of every inline event handlers in my document before they are fired. For static nodes of the document (i.e., nodes that are not dynamically injected by a script), I want to remove the inline event handlers and convert them to external event handlers (external handler means directly calling the `node.AddEventListener` function from JavaScript). For dynamic nodes however, I want to leave the inline event handlers as they are (dynamic nodes are nodes injected using JavaScript).

For example:

```
<body>
<img onerror="alert(1)" />
<script>
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "<img onerror='alert(2)'/>";
</script>
<div id="a"></div>
</body>
```

In the above example, I want the alert(1) error event to be converted into an external event while leaving the alert(2) error event inline. I know how to convert an inline event handler to external, but I don't know how to 1) intercept an inline handler right when it "registers" and before it's actually fired. and 2) differentiate the handlers of static nodes and dynamic nodes.

I understand that this is a difficult problem, but any help/comments would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two useful DOM events you can watch for before your other inline event handlers are fired or registered. You should either watch for [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) or the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29) event.

The `onload` event is fired when all the page content, including all the resources (CSS, JS, images, etc).
`DOMContentLoaded` on the other hand, is fired when the document has finished loading (DOM is ready) but not its dependent resources. Meaning HTML markup, text and styles are ready.

jQuery has a cross-browser [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event for this purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do something when the DOM is ready.
});
```

You can interrupt before the `onerror` event.
You should assign IDs or classes to your elements if you want to play with them easily via javascript (and jQuery): `<img id="img1" onerror="alert(1)" />`. So, let's say you want to get rid of the alert that is fired with the `onerror` event; you can do this for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img1').unbind('error');
    //OR $('img').first().unbind('error'); 
            //to get the first image element from your actual code
});
```

This removes (unbounds) handlers for the `error` event on the `img1` element. If you want to remove error event handlers from all images, you can do this:

```
$('img').unbind('error');
```

If you want to remove the old and assign a new error event to a specific element:

```
$('#img1').unbind('error').error(function(event){
    // do stuff...
});
```

To answer your second question; you cannot really differentiate between the static and dynamically added event handlers. But, simply you can place code before the line(s) that the dynamic handlers are added.

Hope this helps.

Comment: both of these events (window.onload and domcontentloaded) will fire "after" the onerror in my last case so they won't interrupt the onerror event.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to intercept the registration of inline events, **but it is possible to intercept the execution of inline scripts**.

Although browsers don't provide interfaces to control inline events, inline events are also DOM events that observe W3C specifications. To understand the following implements, you'd better have a knowledge of event propagation in the HTML DOM API: [Bubbling and capturing, two ways of event propagation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

According to the article above, in all browsers(except IE<9), there are two stages of event processing. The event first goes down - that’s called *capturing*, and then *bubbles up*. This behavior is standartized in W3C specification. So we can intercept the inline event of a node in the *capturing* stage before it is fired by binding a event to the parent node. For example:

```
<img src="" onerror="alert('Yahoo!');" id="target" />
<script>
    document.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        var element = e.target;
        if (element.id == "target") {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            console.log("The alert is intercepted.");
        }
    }, true);
</script>
```

The event we bind to document above will executed before img.onerror, and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` prevents further propagation of the current event. Thus, there is no chance for the inline onerror event to be fired.

**Reference:** http://fex.baidu.com/blog/2014/06/xss-frontend-firewall-1/